# Prevent Specific Profile/User access to access User Settings

Tags: profile, user

is it possible to prevent specific profiles or users to access their personal User Settings (or at least hide some sections such as "Display & Layout", "Email", ecc)

Thank you

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no permission that grants access to this area, so there's no way to restrict access to this area, short of disabling UI access completely (making the user an Api Only user).